# Setting up django-allauth 404 error?

Tags: django, facebook, authentication, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) to work for a project. In my Django project, lets call it yali, I did a git clone.

I then moved the folder /django-allauth/allauth to root /yali. and then deleted django-allauth and all the licenses, READMEs ...etc

According to documentation, there are three things I should do:

I should add this to settings.py:

```
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account"
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ...
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'emailconfirmation',
    'uni_form',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.twitter',
    'allauth.openid',
    'allauth.facebook',
```

And then add this to urls.py

```
(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')))
```

Doing so, gives me a 404 when navigating to http://localhost:8000/account

What am I missing here? The documentation is somewhat unclear here and even potentially wrong. It instructs to point urls.py to "accounts", while there is no "accounts" folder but "account"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder name has nothing to do with the url. The [urls of your apps are defined in `urls.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). You can put what you want, but you must use those same urls when navigating in the browser.

In your case, you must navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts
```

If you have defined urls as:

```
(r'^anything/', include('allauth.urls')))
```

you should navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8000/anything
```

Comment: Thanks, that made sense, feeling stupid. still can't vote up  till I get 15.